# Obtain Picasa AlbumID

Tags: android, api, picasa

In Picasa I created an album, let´s say Test:

```
 public void CreateAlbum(String title, String description){

    AlbumEntry myAlbum = new AlbumEntry();

    myAlbum.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(title));
    myAlbum.setDescription(new PlainTextConstruct(description));
       try {
        AlbumEntry insertedEntry = myPicasa.insert(postUrl, myAlbum);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       Log.d("CREATE ALBUM", "ALBUM ID"+ myAlbum.getId());

    }
```

And to upload I need this posturl:

```
albumPostUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/USERNAME/albumid/ALBUMID);
```

But the ALBUMID is a code, that I can get when I go online to Picasa and check the browser (after clicking RSS), but how can I get that ALBUMID if I just created an album by calling the method with for example title TEST?

The Logcat shows album id null.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

answer in the api for [BaseEntry](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/BaseEntry#getId%28%29)

```
String id = myPicasa.insert(postUrl, myAlbum).getID();
```

your AlbumEntry is a subclass of BaseEntry. 
code above will return the id you asked for.